# Prove that $ 4^{n} + 6n - 10$ is divisible by $18$, $ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: proof-verification, induction, divisibility

**Question:**

Prove that $ 4^{n} + 6n - 10$ is divisible by $18$, $ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

**My attempt:**

Proof by Induction:

Base Case:

$ n = 1,  4^1 + 6(1) - 10 = 0 = 18(0)$. So base case holds.

I.H: Assume $ \ 4^{k} + 6k -10 = 18m$ for some $ m \in \mathbb{Z},\  k \in \mathbb{N}$.

WTP $ \ 4^{k+1} + 6(k+1) - 10 = 18m$.

$ 4^{k+1} + 6(k+1) - 10 = 4\cdot4^k +6k + 6 -10 = 4(18m + 10 -6k) + 6k + 6 -10$ , by I.H.

$ 4(18m + 10 -6k) + 6k + 6 -10 = 72m +40 - 18k -4 = 72m -18k +36 = 18(4m -k +2)$.

Hence by induction, the result holds for all natural numbers.

I have seen similar proofs in which instead of substituting an expression using the induction hypotheses, the $ k+1$ statement is manipulated until its brought in the desired form. Can I use the induction hypothesis to sub in $ \ 4^{k}$ like this? Is this approach correct?

Comment: Your base case seems to have a minor typo. 8(0) should be 18(0)?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof looks okay.

Here is an alternate approach:

mod $18$, we have
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
n&1&2&3&4&\cdots\\
\hline
4^n&4&16&10&4&\cdots\\
\hline
6n&6&12&0&6&\cdots
\end{array}
$$
Since each column is dependent only on the previous one, the sequences for $4^n$ and $6n$ repeat every $3$ columns. Also from the table above,
$$
4^n+6n-10\equiv0\pmod{18}
$$
will also repeat every $3$ columns.

Answer (score 1):

With the corrections shown, your approach is fine. This is my version of an inductive proof.

According to the binomial theorem
\begin{align}
   (1+3)^n 
   &= 1 + 3\binom{n}{1} + 3^2 \binom{n}{2} + 3^3 \binom{n}{3} \dots + 3^n \\
   &= 1 + 3n + 9 \cdot \text{(some integer)}
\end{align}

We check the first few examples

\begin{align}
4^0 &= 1 + 3 \cdot 0 + 9 \cdot 0 \\
4^1 &= 1 + 3 \cdot 1 + 9 \cdot 0 \\
4^2 &= 1 + 3 \cdot 2 + 9 \cdot 1 \\
4^3 &= 1 + 3 \cdot 3 + 9 \cdot 6 \\
4^4 &= 1 + 3 \cdot 4 + 9 \cdot 27 \\
\end{align}

The conclusion is that $9$ divides  $4^n - 1 - 3n$.

This is easily varified by mathematical induction:

> We have shown it is true for $n=0$
>   and $4^{k+1} - 1 - 3(k+1) = 4(4^k - 1 - 3k)$, which is a 
>   multiple of $9$,

Then $4^n + 6n - 10 = (4^n - 1 - 3n) + (9n - 9)$ which is a multiple of $9$.

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct to me.

You have shown that
if the hypothesis is true for $k$
then it is true for $k+1$.

Full credit.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove it without induction.

Our number is even.

Thus, it remains to prove that this number divided by $9$.

Indeed,
$$4^n+6n-10=4^n-1+6n-9=(4-1)(4^{n-1}+4^{n-2}+...+4+1)+6n-9=$$
$$=3\left(4^{n-1}-1+4^{n-2}-1+...+4-1+n\right)+6n-9=9K+9n-9,$$
where $K$ is an integer number 
and we are done!

Answer (score -1):

Nit-pick: Your WTP should be $4^{k+1}+6(k+1)-10=18\cdot m'$ for some $m' \in \mathbb{Z}$, rather than using the specific $m$ from the IH